# Turning It On and Off

Tags: electronics

I just bought a raspberry pi 3 on eBay that came with all the games.  I can't get it to turn on. I have the power source plugged into the wall and the cdmi is in the tv. How do I turn it on?  Do I need a keyboard?

Comment: please post a link to eBay

Answer (score 1):

You switch a Pi on by applying power (5V) via the microUSB socket.

The Pi does not have an on/off switch.

There needs to be a SD card with a bootable image in the SD card slot for the Pi to boot.